# строка выводится 2 раза

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

после победы над монстром предложение "помочь бедолаге" выводится 2 раз

```
def meetVillage():
    global hp
    global coins
    global damage

    MMonsterLvl = r.randint(1, 5)
    mmonsterHp = MMonsterLvl * 6
    MMonsterDmg = MMonsterLvl * 6 - 1
    MMonsters = ['Орк', 'Огр', 'Демонид', 'Скелет', 'Слизь', 'Гоблин', 'Жаба гигант', 'Лич']
    MMonster = r.choice(MMonsters)

    Villages = ['Лия', 'По', 'Мия', 'Пуа', 'Муа', 'Лулу', 'Ханс', 'Али']
    Village = r.choice(Villages)

    WWeaponLvl = r.randint(1, 5)
    WWeaponDmg = r.randint(4, 10) * WWeaponLvl + damage
    WWeapons = ['стальной меч', 'кинжал', 'посох', 'титановый меч', 'топор мясника', 'лук', 'арбалет', 'копье']
    WWeaponRarities = ['испорченный', 'обычный', 'редкий', 'мифический', 'легендарный']
    WWeaponRarity = WWeaponRarities[WWeaponLvl]
    WWeaponCost = r.randint (5, 18) * WWeaponLvl
    WWeapon = r.choice(WWeapons)

    print('вы дошли до небольшой деревеньки! \nпри желании вы можете выполнить задания жителей за вознаграждение')

    printParameters

    while True:
        choice1 = input('Хотите пройтись по деревне? (да/нет):').lower()
        if choice1 == 'да':
            print ('Вы гугляли по деревушке и рассматривали товары на рынке.')
            print ('Вдруг к вам подбежал житель и попросил о помощи')
            print('{0}:\n- Здравствуй добрый путник, прошу помоги мне.\n- у речки на западе, недалеко отсюда поселился монстр, который травит воду в реке \n- одолей монстра и я дам тебе щедрое вознаграждение'.format(Village))

            while True:
                choice2 = input('Помочь бедолаге? (да/нет):').lower()
                if choice2 == 'да':
                    print('Вы согласились помочь и пошли к речке')
                    print('На речке вы встретили {0} {1} уровня, у него {2} жизней и {3} урона'.format(MMonster, MMonsterLvl, mmonsterHp, MMonsterDmg))
                    while mmonsterHp > 0:
                        choice3 = input ('Хотите атаковать его? (да/нет):')
                        if choice3 == 'да':
                            
                            mmonsterHp -= damage
                            print ('Ты атаковал монстра, у него осталось', mmonsterHp, 'жизней.')

                        elif choice3 == 'нет':
                            chance1 = r.randint(0, 3)
                            if chance1 == 0:
                                print ('Вы убежали достаточно далеко, оглянувшись вы подумали- ')
                                print ('"Вроде убежал"')
                                print ('Вы вернулись в деревню.')
                                print('Узнав об произошедшем, жители деревни огорчились. Монстр продолжил травить воду в реке.')
                                break
                            else:
                                print ('Вы попытались убежать, но монстр оказался быстрее.')
                        else:
                            continue
                        if mmonsterHp > 0:
                            hp -= MMonsterDmg
                            print ('Монстр атаковал вас, у вас осталось', hp, 'жизней')
                        if hp <= 0:
                            break
                    else:
                        loot1 = 'шкура монстра'
                        print('Тебе удалось одолеть монстра, из него выпала', loot1)

                elif choice2 == 'нет':
                    print ('Вы осмотрелись в деревне, затем покинули её')
                    print ('Вы продолжили свой путь.')

            else:
                print ('Вы продолжили свой путь.')
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема вашего цикла в том, что вы ставите `else` после `while`. Я вас советую использовать конструкцию не `while True`, а `while 'your_variable'` и просто меняете значение с `True` на `False` и наоборот. И да, есть ещё одна ошибка в строке `WWeaponLvl = r.randint(1, 5)`, вам же она нужна в качестве индекса, правильно будет: `WWeaponLvl = r.randint(0, 4)`

```
    while True:
        choice1 = input('Хотите пройтись по деревне? (да/нет):').lower()
        if choice1 == 'да':
            print ('Вы гугляли по деревушке и рассматривали товары на рынке.')
            print ('Вдруг к вам подбежал житель и попросил о помощи')
            print('{0}:\n- Здравствуй добрый путник, прошу помоги мне.\n- у речки на западе, недалеко отсюда поселился монстр, который травит воду в реке \n- одолей монстра и я дам тебе щедрое вознаграждение'.format(Village))

            while True:
                choice2 = input('Помочь бедолаге? (да/нет):').lower()
                if choice2 == 'да':
                    print('Вы согласились помочь и пошли к речке')
                    print('На речке вы встретили {0} {1} уровня, у него {2} жизней и {3} урона'.format(MMonster, MMonsterLvl, mmonsterHp, MMonsterDmg))
                    while mmonsterHp > 0:
                        choice3 = input ('Хотите атаковать его? (да/нет):')
                        if choice3 == 'да':
                            
                            mmonsterHp -= damage
                            print ('Ты атаковал монстра, у него осталось', mmonsterHp, 'жизней.')

                        elif choice3 == 'нет':
                            chance1 = r.randint(0, 3)
                            if chance1 == 0:
                                print ('Вы убежали достаточно далеко, оглянувшись вы подумали- ')
                                print ('"Вроде убежал"')
                                print ('Вы вернулись в деревню.')
                                print('Узнав об произошедшем, жители деревни огорчились. Монстр продолжил травить воду в реке.')
                                break
                            else:
                                print ('Вы попытались убежать, но монстр оказался быстрее.')
                        else:
                            continue
                        if mmonsterHp > 0:
                            hp -= MMonsterDmg
                            print ('Монстр атаковал вас, у вас осталось', hp, 'жизней')
                        if hp <= 0:
                            break

                    loot1 = 'шкура монстра'
                    print('Тебе удалось одолеть монстра, из него выпала', loot1)
                    break

                elif choice2 == 'нет':
                    print ('Вы осмотрелись в деревне, затем покинули её')
                    print ('Вы продолжили свой путь.')

            print ('Вы продолжили свой путь.')
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: помогло, но частично, теперь повторяется "Хотите пройтись по деревне? (да/нет):"

Comment: Поставьте `break` после последнего принта, исправил ответ, можете принять его как ответ на ваш вопрос